# How do i create a number of inputs from an input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm brand new to this, 10 days in.

I've been thinking how I could solve this for 30 min. Please help.

> ### Find Average
>
> You need to calculate the average of a collection of values. Every value will be valid number. The average must be printed with two digits after the decimal point.
>
> #### Input-
>
> On the first line, you will receive N - the number of the values you must read
> On the next N lines you will receive numbers.
>
> #### Output-
>
> On the only line of output, print the average with two digits after the decimal point.
>
> ```
> Input
> 4
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> Output
> 1.00
>
> Input 
> 3
> 2.5
> 1.25
> 3
> Output
> 2.25
> ```

From what I see, I figure I need to create as much inputs as the N of the first one is and then input the numbers Id like to average and then create a formula to average them. I may be completely wrong in my logic, in any case Id be happy for some advice.

So far I tried creating a while loop to create inputs from the first input. But have no clue about the proper syntax and continue with making the new inputs into variables I can use

```
a=int(input())
x=1
while x<a or x==a:
    float(input())
    x=x+1
```

Comment: the entire data is received within one `input()` call.
the return value of `input()` is a `string`.
then you can split the string into pieces and use the pieces to calculate the average.

I'm not adding any code because I believe you should solve this yourself, another tip - google searching for python builtin methods that may help (e.g - "how to split a string").

Comment: @Daniel The input is on separate lines, they appeared on one line due to a formatting error

Comment: Why are you using `int()` when the numbers seem to be `float`s?

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to say that. Thank you for the answer tho. Knowing now that they are separate inputs, do you have any guidance?

Comment: @mousetail Good point, simply missed it, didnt pay enough mind before getting a wrong console output. Will correct now : )

Comment: Maybe try if you can output the sum first? A easier first step

Comment: @mousetail The sum is an avarage of the N new inputs depending on the first. The answers are just examples of what output i should get for the input. I can only output the sum after creating a number of inputs.Sorry if Im missing what you meant.

Comment: No the sum is not a average. Please edit your code to print the sum first. Just because it's a easier task. After that you can try to modify it to print the average instead

Comment: I am sorry. Mixed up what i meant.But even the sum of the numbers depends on my first N variable.I cannot think of a way to make the inputs coming out of the first N variable into variables so I can start making a formula. Basically for now my code runs like this. I put the first input , ex 4, it allows me to add 4 new inputs and the code ends.But thes new inputs are not in any way represented in my code and can start using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few things that you were doing wrong. when the numbers are decimals use `float` not `int`.

If you are looking for a single line input this should be how it's done.

When writing the code please use proper variables and add a string that's asking for the input.

```
total = 0

first_num=int(input("Number of inputs: "))
number = input("Enter numbers: ")
input_nums = number.split()
    

for i in range(first_num):
    total = total + int(input_nums[i])


average = total/first_num
print(average)
```

If you are looking for a multiline output This should be how it's done.

```
first_num=int(input("Number of inputs: "))
x=1
total = 0
while x<first_num or x==first_num:
    number = float(input("Enter numbers: "))
    total = total + number
    x=x+1

avg = total/first_num
print(avg)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Im new here, I cant even upvote you, but I really appreciate it.

Comment: @StefanPeev you can mark the answer as correct if is. the tick mark

Comment: Didnt know that. Done :) 
Btw, for the correct 100 points answer the print was 
print(f'{avg:.2f}') so I can get 2 decimals.

Comment: @StefanPeev You didn't add mine as correct. check about ```round()``` to round

Comment: oh, I didnt know I can choose only one :D sorry , was giving them out.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=int(input('Total number of input: '))

total = 0.0

for i in range(a):
    total += float(input(f'Input #{i+1}: '))
    
print('average: ', round(total/a,2))
```

Modified a bit on your version to make it work

Comment: Thank you. I tried first with a range but found it more difficult to figure it out.

Comment: don't forget to round to the hundredths place: print('average: ', round(total / a, 2))